# How to send an HTML file with images using express

Tags: html, node.js, express

How to send an HTML file with images using express?

This is my code for handeling the first page (index.html) to the user. But in this page their are stuff like this: img src = ... and more, and sendFile transfer only text of the page. How do I send css file, images and more?

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For static files (like css and images, etc) you use:

```
app.use(express.static('/public));
```

More info can be found at http://www.expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html